# Strange error when connecting JTAG

Tags: arm, jtag, openocd

My setup:

Common) CPU: at91sam7x512, JTAG: olimex-arm-usb-tiny-h, proprietary single-CPY board
1) Windows 7, OpenOCD 0.0.4     <- works
2) Ubuntu 13.04, OpenOCD 0.7.0  <- strange error

There are some config files written in past times and the windows version works. Now I am trying to make things work under linux.

The [manufacturer's page](https://www.olimex.com/Products/ARM/JTAG/ARM-USB-TINY-H/) doesn't seem to have a ready config file, although they have instructions for building OpenOCD.

I built it with ft2232 support. OpenOCD seems to locate the JTAG, but not the device:

```
sw3@pc90313-sw3:~/ocd_conf$ openocd -f ocdconfig.cfg 
Open On-Chip Debugger 0.7.0 (2013-08-16-13:27)
Licensed under GNU GPL v2
For bug reports, read
    http://openocd.sourceforge.net/doc/doxygen/bugs.html
Info : only one transport option; autoselect 'jtag'
adapter speed: 20 kHz
srst_only srst_pulls_trst srst_gates_jtag srst_open_drain connect_deassert_srst
Info : device: 6 "2232H"
Info : deviceID: 364511274
Info : SerialNumber: OLWKRKY?A
Info : Description: Olimex OpenOCD JTAG ARM-USB-TINY-H A
Info : max TCK change to: 30000 kHz
Info : clock speed 20 kHz
fError: couldn't read enough bytes from FT2232 device (70 < 81)
Error: couldn't read from FT2232
Error: Trying to use configured scan chain anyway...
Warn : Bypassing JTAG setup events due to errors
Info : Embedded ICE version 1
Info : sam7x512.cpu: hardware has 2 breakpoint/watchpoint units
```

Here is my config file:

```
sw3@pc90313-sw3:~/ocd_conf$ cat ocdconfig.cfg 
source [find interface/olimex-arm-usb-tiny-h.cfg]

adapter_khz 20

source [find target/at91sam7x512.cfg]
```

This error `Error: couldn't read enough bytes from FT2232 device (70 < 81)` seems to be the give-away. Other people in Googleland have experienced similar problems, but with (0 < 81) in which case it is clear that communication is not working at all. In my case, the number oscillates at 69-79-71.

Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The FT2232H uses High Speed USB, and the error translates into "problem in USB communication". I`d recommend trying another USB cable first - but this seems not to be a problem here, as it works in other configurations.

You should use the newer `ftdi` driver in OpenOCD `0.7.0`:

```
source [find interface/ftdi/olimex-arm-usb-tiny-h.cfg]
```

You can ignore the warning, the interface was tested to be OK, but after the `0.7.0` release.

Updating the [OpenOCD windows binaries](http://www.freddiechopin.info/en/download/category/4-openocd) might be a good idea, too - the `0.4.0` release is getting rusty.

Comment: I ... am not sire if this worked. There are no errors with the new interface. Is `openocd` supposed to run as a deamon so that I can connect to it from e.g. gdb, or is it supposed to enter interactive mode and expect commands?

Comment: Deamon mode: Use `telnet localhost 4444` in another console. You might also want to RTFM.

Comment: OK, thanks. TFM is 150 pages ... I'm going through it, but am not understanding everything at the first run.

Comment: Thanks, changing the interface eliminated the error. I was suspecting my libftd2xx.so and looping in circles until your answer. l