# openOCD flash 'erase_sector' command NOT erasing lpc1768?

Tags: jtag, lpc, openocd

I am trying to debug LPC1768 using a JTAG debugger and openOCD(version 0.7.0). My os is Win7 .

I'm connetced to the openOCD via telnet(port 4444)
commands like **halt**, **flash info**, **resume** etc do work peoperly.

Now when I do

```
flash erase_sector 0 0 0
```

I get the follow reply

```
erased sectors 0 through 0 on flash bank 0 in 5.705326s
```

then I do

```
mdw 0 7
```

and it returns

```
0x00000000: 10001ffc 1fff0081 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
```

What are those first two words?
Should it not be all **ffffffff**?

[image: Snapshot CMD]

UPDATE

flash write_bank too has no effect on flash.

I then uploaded the same binary using H-JTAG and it got programmed. So that means my chip isn't bricked!

[image]

content of my openocd cfg file

```
interface parport
gdb_port 3333

gdb_memory_map enable
gdb_flash_program enable

source [find board/mcb1700.cfg]
```

contents of mcb1700.cfg

```
# Keil MCB1700 PCB with 1768
# 
# Reset init script sets it to 100MHz
set CCLK 100000 

source [find target/lpc1768.cfg] 

interface parport
parport_port 0x378
parport_cable wiggler

global MCB1700_CCLK
set MCB1700_CCLK $CCLK

$_TARGETNAME configure -event reset-start {
    # Start *real slow* as we do not know the
    # state the boot rom left the clock in
    adapter_khz 100
}

# Set up 100MHz clock to CPU
$_TARGETNAME configure -event reset-init {
    # PLL0CON: Disable PLL
    mww 0x400FC080 0x00000000
    # PLLFEED
    mww 0x400FC08C 0x000000AA
    # PLLFEED
    mww 0x400FC08C 0x00000055

    # CCLK=PLL/4 (=100 MHz)
    mww 0x400FC104 0x00000003
    # CLKSRCSEL: Clock source = internal RC oscillator
    mww 0x400FC10C 0x00000000

    # PLL0CFG: M=50,N=1 -> PLL=400 MHz
    mww 0x400FC084 0x00000031
    # PLLFEED
    mww 0x400FC08C 0x000000AA
    # PLLFEED
    mww 0x400FC08C 0x00000055

    # PLL0CON: Enable PLL
    mww 0x400FC080 0x00000001
    # PLLFEED
    mww 0x400FC08C 0x000000AA
    # PLLFEED
    mww 0x400FC08C 0x00000055

    sleep 50

    # PLL0CON: Connect PLL
    mww 0x400FC080 0x00000003
    # PLLFEED
    mww 0x400FC08C 0x000000AA
    # PLLFEED
    mww 0x400FC08C 0x00000055

    # Dividing CPU clock by 8 should be pretty conservative
    #
    # 
    global MCB1700_CCLK
    adapter_khz [expr $MCB1700_CCLK / 8]

    # Do not remap 0x0000-0x0020 to anything but the flash (i.e. select
    # "User Flash Mode" where interrupt vectors are _not_ remapped,
    # and reside in flash instead).
    #
    # See Table 612. Memory Mapping Control register (MEMMAP - 0x400F C040) bit description
    # Bit Symbol Value Description Reset
    # value
    # 0 MAP Memory map control. 0
    # 0 Boot mode. A portion of the Boot ROM is mapped to address 0.
    # 1 User mode. The on-chip Flash memory is mapped to address 0.
    # 31:1 - Reserved. The value read from a reserved bit is not defined. NA
    #
    # http://ics.nxp.com/support/documents/microcontrollers/?scope=LPC1768&type=user

    mww 0x400FC040 0x01
}
```

contents of lpc1768.cfg

```
# NXP LPC1768 Cortex-M3 with 512kB Flash and 32kB+32kB Local On-Chip SRAM,
set CHIPNAME lpc1768
set CPUTAPID 0x4ba00477
set CPURAMSIZE 0x8000
set CPUROMSIZE 0x80000

# After reset the chip is clocked by the ~4MHz internal RC oscillator.
# When board-specific code (reset-init handler or device firmware)
# configures another oscillator and/or PLL0, set CCLK to match; if
# you don't, then flash erase and write operations may misbehave.
# (The ROM code doing those updates cares about core clock speed...)
#
# CCLK is the core clock frequency in KHz
set CCLK 4000

#Include the main configuration file.
source [find target/lpc17xx.cfg];
```

Comment: Try `flash erase_sector 0 0 last` -< erase the whole first flash bank.

Comment: I tried that as well. No effect!

Comment: Another idea. Try flashing the chip with `program` or `flash write_image` and see if those succeed. If there are problems again, consider hardware erase of the whole chip, if available. The chip might be locked for some reason.

Comment: If you are having problems with the JTAG hardware (which sounds unlikely), you can try [using the ftdi driver in place of the fd2232](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/79465/9910)

Comment: @Vorac My JTAG is a LTP based wiggler clone. And I highly suspect its frequency settings. I'm trying to lower the frequency now!

Comment: Are the flash sectors/pages write protected? Try disable: `monitor flash protect 0 0 127 off` This code is for STM32F1 with 256 KB falsh and 2KB page size. OpenOCD will help to know proper values for your uC.
It is recommended turn protection on after firmware loaded. `monitor flash protect 0 0 127 off`

Comment: did you try flash write address?  that recently worked for me on an NXP part when the others didnt.

Comment: @dewlch I was working on the LPC1768 back in 2013. I do not recall what else I had tried that time. What I recall is that I had to buy a new board that time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot:

```
reset init
```

Background: The LPC1768 maps a ROM bootloader by default at addess `0x0`. The `reset init` handler in recent OpenOCD version does the remapping to flash memory.

Comment: So I should be doing **reset init** followed by **erase** followed by **flash** followed by *gdb debugging*  ?

Comment: I'm getting this[https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B_OcX1Wr8s5WUzhUY0QwdUpfUjQ/edit?usp=sharing] Error!   Also check the mcb1700.cfg file content in update! seems some mww error. but where?

Comment: Make sure the SRST line is connected and use `reset_config srst_only separate`

Comment: Also, looks a bit like your JTAG speed is too high.

Comment: The JTAG-Adapter works well with H-JTAG which doesn't provides GDB debug capability. `reset_config srst_only seperate` gives this(https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B_OcX1Wr8s5WYVp1UGVVNzA5MTA/edit?usp=sharing) output. What JTAG speed should I use here?

Comment: Clean your glasses: Its spells `separate`. It says so in the message, btw.

Comment: Aww Sorry, my sleepy eyes. Seems the command `reset_config srst_only separate` did something cool(?). Now `reset init` has no complaints. Also, the flash erase command did erased the flash. But Somehow 'flash write_bank` isn't working even now. Take a look at this(https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B_OcX1Wr8s5WcERla3VULTcwUHc/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10392/discussion-between-vvy-and-turbo-j)