# openOCD : how do I know if my LPT-JTAG adapter is in sync?

Tags: jtag, openocd

My openocd config file has the following content

```
interface parport
gdb_port 3333    
gdb_memory_map enable
gdb_flash_program enable

source [find board/mcb1700.cfg]
```

when I launch openOCD with this config file I get follow

[image]

The JTAG adapter is a wiggler clone.

Does this confirms if the JTAG-adapter is in sync with target?

How/Where to reduce the adapter and target communication speed?

[I'm unable to program/Erase the LPC1768 target via openOCD.](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/80633/openocd-flash-erase-sector-command-not-erasing-lpc1768)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does this confirms if the JTAG-adapter is in sync with target?

OpenOCD would otherwise print diagnostic messages: `Polling target failed [...]`.

> How/Where to reduce the adapter and target communication speed

It is already at a low 10 kHz. You can change it in ther terminal (port 4444) or in the config file with:

```
adapter_khz 500
```

More than 500 kHz is not recommended - the MCU runs at 4 MHz by default and requires JTAG clock to be lower than CCLK/4.